# How to add more than one image in the question body in one attempt?

Tags: support, feature-request

I have problem inserting more than one image. Every time I try, it requires me to upload one photo at a time.

Can I mark more than one image from my gallery when trying to upload pictures (so that I don't have to upload every picture separately)?

If it's not possible, can we have this feature in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the [support](/questions/tagged/support) part:

You can’t upload more than one image at a time. SE’s image uploader has never supported adding batch images.

On the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request):

If you want to request this feature, I think you should post it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) instead of here. Meta Stack Exchange is where users discuss site features common to all SE sites, including the image uploader. Posting there would make your request more visible to the SE team and other users who might be interested in this feature.